# Maven, different database url for test and dev

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I want to use in memory database when running `mvn test` and a file-backed database in development. I have filters "working" in that I run `mvn resources:resources` I get the templates in `src/main/resources` rendered correctly into the `target/classes` directory. Using Grizzly in my Main class, the webserver does pickup the `hibernate.cfg.xml` in `target/classes`.

However, when I run `mvn test`, it seems that the `hibernate.cfg.xml` is read as the raw template in `src/main/resources` rather than what is rendered in `target/classes`. How can I get `mvn test` (and running tests from intellij) to use the filtered/rendered resources?

Comment: Inject you db connection using spring.

Comment: I'm using Jersey and would rather not bring on a big dependency for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put the test config file in `src/test/resources` so at `test` time it will take precedence (in classpath)

Comment: This does work. But, sad that there is not a DRYer solution using filtering.

Comment: anyhow you would have to specify two xml files right ? or do some programatic hack that detects its in test mode and then choose the data source